# Dealing with very old off-topic questions?

Tags: discussion, moderation, off-topic

For some reason [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/108072/bare-metal-virtualisation-for-the-desktop) is getting up-voted and answered, even though it is clearly off-topic.

It would be more appropriate for superuser.

Answer (score 5):

It was asked in September 2008, which is very early in the lifecycle of the site. We're not quite two years old yet.

That said, I agree, and I migrated it to Super User -- which didn't exist then, either.

That is the general policy I suggest, if you encounter very old questions that should be migrated (or closed/deleted as off-topic depending on the degree of off-topic-ness) just flag them.

We do have a handful of questions that are effectively grandfathered in, like Favorite Programming Cartoon. These would be closed within seconds if asked today, but we allow them as part of the historical record.

Comment: but a programming cartoon is at least kind of, you know, programming related...

Comment: +1 for that last paragraph; I'm sure I'll need to cite it in some future discussion about what is programming-related.