# How do I word this in a less subjective way?

Tags: discussion, subjective, wording

I accidentally worded this in a subjective way: [Language-agnostic libs every programmer should know?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3764149/language-agnostic-libs-every-programmer-should-know-closed)

I was just wondering how I can ask the question in an acceptable way. From searching, I've seen the question asked for specific languages:

[What should every JavaScript programmer know?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2628672/what-should-every-javascript-programmer-know)
[What should every PHP programmer know?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/306497/what-should-every-php-programmer-know)

These are not very specific.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/634206/what-every-programmer-should-know-about
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/132798/what-should-every-programmer-know
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/806659/what-are-the-best-habits-of-highly-effective-programmers

So I imagine I **could** ask something similar if I *wrote it properly*. How can I ask the question in a better way?

Comment: One of those mentioned questions has been closed and reopened [a couple times](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/2628672/revisions); at least two others are older than close/reopen history was kept.  Don't take their current non-closed state as meaning they are perfectly acceptable.

Comment: Moreover, don't take the existence of certain questions as a sign that a similar question will be allowed.  Some questions have been generally recognized as part of the history of SO, and therefore grandfathered in.

Comment: +1 @David; [source](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/53528/dealing-with-very-old-off-topic-questions/53531#53531)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that the problem is more that this is an endless question with no definite answer. You might want to put the question up on [programmers.stackexchange.com](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/).

But why are there questions like this from the past? The community used to allow questions in the past that it does not any longer, as the rules change over time and first had to be found.

Language specific questions of the same kind tend to be more narrow, yet I guess that even these would be rejected nowadays, especially since the SE site programmers came along. From its FAQ:

> What kind of questions can I ask here?
>
> Programmers - Stack Exchange is for expert programmers who are interested in subjective discussions on software development.
>
> Please look around to see if your question has already been asked (and maybe even answered!) before you ask. It's also perfectly fine to ask and answer your own question, as long as you pretend you're on Jeopardy: phrase it in the form of a question.